# Error i8::MAX - Constant `MAX` is private [E0603]

Tags: rust

I'm following a beginner's tutorial on Rust. At one point the lecturer printed out std::i8::MAX. I followed suit and noticed that IntelliJ was flagging std::i8::MAX as deprecated.

Following the link to, https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/i8/constant.MAX.html
It shows:

// intended way

```
let max = i8::MAX;
```

So I've updated this simple code to follow the recommendation:

```
fn main() {
    let x:i8 = i8::MAX;
    println!("i8::MAX = {}",x);
}
```

However, now there are 2 interesting issues:

1. The MAX on i8::MAX is indicated with an error that, **Constant `MAX` is private [E0603]**. That seems wrong.
2. The code actually executes, even with the Rust compiler error. If the constant MAX is private, shouldn't I not have access to it? Why does it even run, let alone provide the correct following output:

i8::MAX = 127

I'm running the latest version of IntelliJ with the Rust pluggin. I've installed Rust for the first time on this Win 11 PC. Running...

```
rustc --version
```

returns

```
rustc 1.69.0 (84c898d65 2023-04-16)
```

Comment: can't reproduce

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the IntelliJ Rust plugin, [there's an issue filed already for it](https://github.com/intellij-rust/intellij-rust/issues/10483).

Comment: Oh, nice! I assumed since I'm just starting on this that it was some newbie issue. Thank You @kmdreko

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a bug in IntelliJ: https://github.com/intellij-rust/intellij-rust/issues/10483.